# Is json having compatibility issues?

Tags: php, json, compatibility

Sounds strange right? waiti until you hear the whole story.
Im a junior web develor on my company and we are working with opencart to make our e-shop projects.

We had the task to sync the database of opencart with the database of ATLANTIS or ERP so when new products are available or got an update the e-shop will update automatic.

After some discussion i added json to the table of course but the senior web developer said that there are compatibility issues when json is generated from a non web language for a web language like php.

Its the first time i hear that and i would like to ask if this is true because i never got a full explaination about this.

Comment: JSON is very simple text format. It itself can't have any compatibility issues. Must be that either one of your parties generates invalid json, or the other can't parse valid json correctly.

Comment: According to the [spec](http://www.json.org/): _"JSON is a text format that is completely language independent but uses conventions that are familiar to programmers of the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python, and many others. These properties make JSON an ideal data-interchange language."_ It makes no difference whether it's a web or non-web language doing the generating/parsing. If both languages implement the spec correctly, it will work fine. If you're concerned the generated JSON is bad, run it through [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate

Comment: "non web language like php"? Uh, your senior developer must have gotten his training from a dollar store box of cereal. PHP's entire reason for existing is to build web pages.

Comment: `json_decode` and `json_encode` exist since php 5.2 (that's what the wiki says). I think if there would be any compatibility issues, they would have been detected since a while and fixed. Maybe he didn't said what he meant or you got him wrong or something else?

Comment: @MarcB _"...from a non web language **for** a web language like PHP"_ - The Senior Dev is noting that PHP is a web langauge.

Comment: @War10ck i see so all the above languages theoretically can generate a json object without any problem or limitation on the syntax and the problem can only come from the developer.

Comment: @user3049652 Not exactly. I don't mean to be critical on naming here (so please don't take this as my being snarky)  but the construct is just _JSON_ based on the _JavaScript_ object notation. It's not a _JSON object_. JSON as a format uses many of the same conventions as those languages listed. However, whether or not a language can generate or parse valid JSON depends on whether that functionality is built into the language natively or whether a third-party has developed a library that can accomplish this and adheres to the spec. If you don't mind my asking, what are the two langauges?

Answer (score 4):

JSON is defined by a rather strict and somewhat limiting [spec](http://json.org/).  Any library that conforms to this spec will both read JSON generated by any conforming library, and generate JSON that can be read by any other conforming library.

If you're using a library that "extends" JSON in some way that is obviously bad and non-compliant, but in general this is not a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are no compatibility issues, however, there are some different RFC (request fro comments) and Standards on it.

It is also present that some systems completely disregard such RFCs (RFC 4627, RFC 7159 and the ECMA-404 / ECMA-262 standards are the most common ones).

Finally, since JSON is simply text, it is common-ish (from my personall experience), that legacy machines save text in a bad encode, either disregarding their Endian system, or even using wrong symbols.

Older analysts tend to disregard, as JSON is "easier" do decrypt and use a larger file size, when compared to some custom serializable system they have been using for ages.